# How to access firebase (JS web client API) exported types?

Tags: typescript, firebase

I've just started using Typescript, so I went to look for Firebase types over on `@types/firebase`.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/firebase

[image]

So it seems that the Firebase API ships with types.

But how can I access, if I need to declare them at some point?

For example:

Let's say I want to declare this config object as a "Firebase App Config Object" (don't know how it would be called, though).

```
const config: THE_FIREBASE_CONFIG_TYPE = {       // <--- WHAT SHOULD I PUT AS THE_FIREBASE_CONFIG_TYPE ?
  apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID,
};
```

What documentation should I refer to in order to find out which types to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually look up the types in the [reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js).

From looking at the reference documentation for [`initializeApp`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase#initializeapp), there is no specific type for this config object:

> `initializeApp`

> `initializeApp ( options :  Object ,  name ? :  string ) : App`

> Creates and initializes a Firebase app instance.

So it looks like you should declare it as `Object`, as there is no more specific type for the config.